# Get time jMeter thread has been running

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

Maybe I am just really bad at navigating the JMeter API [site](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/overview-tree.html).

But lets say I want to find out how long a thread has been running for, in a If Controller or a JSR223 sampler how could I do that? [thread group](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/ThreadGroup.html) for example doesn't seem to have what I am look for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, looking into [JMeterThread JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterThread.html) instead. If you use "Scheduler" option of the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) you will be able to use [JMeterThread.getStartTime()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterThread.html#getStartTime--) and [JMeterThread.getEndTime()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterThread.html#getEndTime--) methods.

If you don't use scheduler you could use the following approach:

1. Add JSR223 Test Element (doesn't really matter which one) to the very beginning of your Thread Group and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   ctx.getThread().setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis())
   ```
2. Add another JSR223 Test Element to the end of your Thread Group and use the following code to get current thread duration:

   ```
   long started = ctx.getThread().getStartTime()

   log.info('Thread duration: ' + (System.currentTimeMillis() - started))
   ```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Thread Duration]

`ctx` is a shorthand to [JMeterContextService](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContextService.html) class.

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details on using Groovy in JMeter tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your test under Transaction Controller

And then in Sampler result you can see Load time: 2771 see [Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller)

> Note: when the check box "Include duration of timer and pre-post
>   processors in generated sample" is checked, the time includes all
>   processing within the controller scope, not just the samples.