# How to find the average response time of a whole thread group in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, webdriver, jmeter-plugins

I have multiple thread groups in my jmeter test plan, each thread group represents a use case of my application.
I am also using webdriver for these scenarios.

So I am trying to find out what is the average time that each use is taking. which is basically the thread group avg time.

Any thoughts how I can do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get time jMeter thread has been running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653976/get-time-jmeter-thread-has-been-running)

Comment: It has been addressed here by Dmitri. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44654787/7332423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) at the top level for your Thread Group(s) and make all Samplers children of this Transaction Controller.

This way you will have cumulative information in JMeter [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners)

[image]

or in the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

[image]